# Unlink Google Form by script not working now

Tags: google-apps-script

I am a complete novice at Google Script but have done some amazing things by copying other people's examples. I've had a Google Sheet script working for a few years and a couple of weeks ago it started failing when unlinking a Google Form from its response sheet. I hadn't changed the code at all. I have seen other posts where people say this has been happening but they say its resolved without saying what they did to resolve it (altho' might just be me struggling to navigate the system).

It seems to be on the Issue Tracker as 189445039 but with people saying its OK now.

The code is shown below and I stuck a Logger.log in to make sure I was trying to unlink the right Form. The line of code to set the Form to stop accepting responses seems to have worked so why not the "removeDestination()"? The script is triggered to run every Sunday night and at the moment I am having to resolve the problem manually.

//   Now unlink Form and delete the "Form responses k" Tab just to keep it tidier.

```
 Logger.log("fixdata[k][15] = " + fixdata[k][15]);
 var existingForm = FormApp.openByUrl(fixdata[k][15]);
 existingForm.removeDestination();
 existingForm.setAcceptingResponses(false); 

 var tabss = ss.getSheetByName("Form responses " + k);
 ss.deleteSheet(tabss);
```

10:13:56 AM Notice  Execution started

10:13:59 AM Info    fixdata[k][15] = https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1uIvU5JQI_0JsM9QdMYReXnaMxbtfp535cHLgh_SCwCo/edit

10:13:58 AM Error

Exception: You cannot delete a sheet with a linked form. Please unlink the form first.

FixtureBookingScript    @ Code.gs:226

Line 226 is the line "ss.deleteSheet(tabss);".

If I manually unlink the relevant Form response sheet and run it again of course it works.

Any advice gratefully received.

Comment: Can you point out the specific issue? For what I understand, you unlink the form succesfully, but every sunday night the script runs again. Have you checked if you have a trigger created? You can check it at the script editor on the clock icon at the left.

Comment: The specific issue is that the "existingForm.removeDestination();" piece of code is no longer unlinking the response sheet from the form. As a result, when it tries to delete the response sheet, it fails with the message shown above. This code used to work. I haven't changed it.

Comment: Tried it today - and it worked a treat. Very frustrating having an intermittent problem.

Comment: Has it happened again or it has been working ever since?

Comment: The script runs on a trigger tonight so I'll know tomorrow morning thanks. Fingers crossed!

Comment: Hi, can you update on it? Did it happen again?

Comment: Apologies -been busy. There were 2 forms scheduled to be unlinked and the associated sheets deleted. The trigger ran late evening on the Sunday and the script failed trying to delete the first sheet because it wasn't unlinked. The following Monday morning, I manually unliked the form and manually ran the script. Obviously the first sheet was now deleted because I had unlinked it myself. I expected the script to fail doing the second form but it ran OK. I'm somewhat bemused but at least I can sort it out manually.

Comment: Did the script failed to unlink the form automatically after this? Is the issue concurrent and you have to unlink it manually?

Comment: The script ran perfectly this Sunday, I didn't have to do anything to sort it out. I am totally bemused.

Comment: Worked fine again last night. The code is obviously fine, so all I can assume is it was an "enviromental" thing.  Probably best to close this question now - any idea how I do that?

Comment: I have posted it as community wiki so everyone knows the resolution.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned on the comments, this was a temporary issue and it is not happening anymore.